# MySQL default value error with ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with sql mode ON

Tags: mysql, insert-update, sql-mode

Common query for both create and update contact.
While doing an updation for a field:-
An exception occurred while executing

```
INSERT INTO contact_table 
SET id = '1234',
is_stealth_mode = 1 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
id = LAST_INSERT_ID( id ),
is_stealth_mode = VALUES(is_stealth_mode)
```

General error: 1364 Field 'club_id' doesn't have a default value

contact_table has a field club_id which has default value none and not nullable

```
strict mode is enabled
```

contact_table already has value id = '1234' and 'club_id' = 123

Comment: Edit your question and add the complete error message you are getting. Also add the schema of the table.

Comment: Why isn't id an auto increment column? Is there a primary key?

Comment: contact_table  `id` is auto_increment and that field itself is the primary key.

Comment: Then why are you trying to set it's value? The DB will do that automatically, and you shouldn't be trying to set it's value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify what each column should update to in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause

```
id = LAST_INSERT_ID( id ),
is_stealth_mode = VALUES(is_stealth_mode),
club_id = club_id
```

to keep the existing value

Or

```
id = LAST_INSERT_ID( id ),
is_stealth_mode = VALUES(is_stealth_mode),
club_id = VALUES(club_id)
```

if you want to update the field value

Comment: I want to keep existing value (quite obvious). Suggested query does not work.

Only if you put `club_id` in values with some dummy value, then it's ok, but it's so dirty hack

Comment: @TheGodfather did the first of the above 2 queries not work ? i would think that `club_id = club_id` should keep the existing value ?

Answer (score 0):

"contact_table has a field club_id which has default value none and not nullable"

From your above statement, is it means that club_id doesn't have default value or it's default value is 'NONE'. It seems to be club_id is not nullable and you should provide that value in the query.

Comment: I got this error while updating an existing entry. `club_id` is already there for id = '1234'

Comment: Please provide your table DDL structure and one row values you are trying to update.

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is that just normal `INSERT` is being executed first, and since your DB has `NOT NULL` constraint, it complains. So `ON DUPLICATE` part doesn't really matter (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/17479690/1657819).

One of possible options - put dummy value for `club_id` field, but not use it in `UPDATE` part.

But of course, if no such id exists, then the entry with dummy data will be created.

```sql
    INSERT INTO contact_table 
      SET id = '1234',
      is_stealth_mode = 1 ,
      club_id="dummy"  <---- Note dummy value which is not used in ON DUPLICATE part
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
      id = LAST_INSERT_ID( id ),
      is_stealth_mode = VALUES(is_stealth_mode)
```

As an alternative, you can change the schema to allow NULL values:

```
ALTER TABLE contact_table
    CHANGE COLUMN `club_id` `club_id` INT NULL <...>
```